# Protractor elementexplorer doesn't show elements

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, jasmine, protractor

I'm starting working with protractor e2e tests and I spend a lot of time in elementexplorer tool. Quite often it doesn't seem to work properly like in this case:

```
node node_modules/protractor/bin/elementexplorer.js http://localhost:9000/#/experiment-desc
Type <tab> to see a list of locator strategies.
Use the `list` helper function to find elements by strategy:
  e.g., list(by.binding('')) gets all bindings.

Getting page at: http://localhost:9000/#/experiment-desc
> element.all(by.css('.hbpreg-exdesc-samples-ul>li'))
```

So I hit the Enter button and nothing happens: my cursor just jumps to the new line and apparently elementexplorer is waiting for more input. I'm trying that on chrome (Chrome Developer Tools are closed). In my tests the locator `element.all(by.css('.hbpreg-exdesc-samples-ul>li'))` works perfectly fine.

Has anyone faced the similar problem?

Comment: Is this always happening then you use `element.all()`? Could you elaborate into a reproducable example (some public page)? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was fixed [Oct 1](https://github.com/angular/protractor/commit/1a4eea4eb89362822dc86be6904c1ddfba95661e) and  got [released in Protractor 1.4.0](https://github.com/angular/protractor/releases).

So you need Protractor >= 1.4.0 or start using master branch.

#### How to install Protractor from master branch

In case you need `sudo` and using Protractor globally installed:

```
sudo npm -g install git://github.com/angular/protractor#master
```

I prefer to setup a NodeJS project with package.json and point to an specific Protractor version or commit, for better control:

```
npm init
npm install --save git://github.com/angular/protractor#ed1c75c7
mkdir -p bin
# some handy shortcuts
ln -s ../node_modules/.bin/protractor bin/p
ln -s ../node_modules/protractor/bin/elementexplorer.js bin/e
# elementexplorer sample usage
bin/e https://angularjs.org/
# Protractor binary sample usage
bin/p your-config.js
```

Comment: That's supposed to be [fixed since 1.0.0](https://github.com/angular/protractor/commit/48798b0a8ac1fc56d0cdd80e177d67fdf592069c) however it might have broken again after [#1296](https://github.com/angular/protractor/pull/1296)